# Limit upload speed on local IIS

Tags: iis, iis-8

I am developing a site where I want to test my AJAX uploader, but I am failing to simulate this on my local IIS. I read a lot articles and tried already the following:

- IIS maxBandwidth
- [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
- [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)
- SpeedSim

The first three only limit download and the third one did not even start. In Charles you can select a upload speed limit, but even if set at 256 kbps my uploads runs with >2 MB/s (the file uploaded has ~2.5 MB) and finishes "instantly".

Does someone know any other tool or method for this?

Comment: So are you trying to limit upload speed into IIS, or are you trying to simulate a slow connection at the client end?

Comment: Yes, INTO IIS as I am testing uploading files from the client TO the server. It is to test the upload progress bar - if the upload is done in <1s there is not much to see...